# Concept of Absolute value

Tags: absolute-value

I need to resolve this misconception quickly.
The question is very simple,
may I derive $|\sqrt y| = x-1$ from $y = (x-1)^2$, such that $x = |\sqrt y|+1$?

Comment: The square root is always positive. What you need is a $\pm$.

Answer (score 0):

From $y=(x-1)^2$ you get
$$\sqrt y=|x-1|\to x= 1\pm\sqrt y$$